# User can't connect to a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I have an WinForms app in the enterprise, which makes a connection to a SQL Server 2008 box.  A lone user can't seem to make a connection.  He brings his laptop and plugs it into the network.  The laptop is not joined to the domain, but the connection to the SQL Server is not through Windows authentication.

I can ping the SQL Server from his laptop.  I tried creating a UDL file and connecting and that does not work either.  The error:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or
>   access denied.

Here are facts:

- The user can connect to any other SQL Server on the network.
- No other user (on the domain or not) has this issue.
- I had the user VPN into the network, with same results.
- I tried connecting my personal laptop (not on the domain, but attached to the office network) and was able to connect with no problems.
- I VPNed from home into the network and was able to connect with no issues.

What else can I do to troubleshoot the connectivity issue?

Comment: You could try using [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865) on this machine and another one, and see what differences there are in the traffic (I'd advise shutting down as many services and apps as possible so that most of the traffic you observe is relevant)

Comment: Check the firewall settings on the problematic notebok, get telnet (or similar port tester) to check if you can access the 1433 port on SQL Server (pinging doesn't help), check for firewall rules related to the server where SQL Server is running (IP restrictions,etc)

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue. Tried to check network connection, port, firewall, etc but no use.
Finally, I realized the top order of Default Document was not default.aspx. After I changed the it on the top, it worked.